Special requirements for CPUs on Exchange in VMware ESXi?
I just ran the Exchange Health Checker script for something unrelated to CPUs, and I noticed at the top of the output in Exchange Management Shell it says:

Virtual Machine detected.  Certain settings about the host hardware cannot be detected from the virtual machine.  Verify on the VM Host that:

There is no more than a 1:1 Physical Core to Virtual CPU ratio (no oversubscribing)
If Hyper-Threading is enabled do NOT count Hyper-Threaded cores as physical cores
Do not oversubscribe memory or use dynamic memory allocation

Although Exchange technically supports up to a 2:1 physical core to vCPU ratio, a 1:1 ratio is strongly recommended for performance reasons.  Certain third party Hyper-Visors such as VMWare have their own guidance.
VMWare recommends a 1:1 ratio.  Their guidance can be found at https://aka.ms/HC-VMwareBP2019
Related specifically to VMWare, if you notice you are experiencing packet loss on your VMXNET3 adapter, you may want to review the following article from VMWare:  https://aka.ms/HC-VMwareLostPackets.
For further details, please review the virtualization recommendations on Microsoft Docs here: https://aka.ms/HC-Virtualization.

Our ESXi 8.0 U2 server has one Intel CPU with 6 physical cores, 12 threads.
Exchange is probably the most important VM on this server, so we had set it to be able to use all of these cores, like this:

We only allocate max CPUs for this one VM - our other VMs are allocated much less CPUs.
VMware's Exchange best practices PDF linked in the script's output above is very detailed, and it talks about CPUs on pages 7-12.
If I understand it correctly, is it saying that for Exchange 2019, you can use any number of cores - as long as the number of sockets is not more than 2, and that Hyperthreading is ok to be enabled nowadays (where it wasn't before)?
Is our CPU configuration shown in the screenshot above okay?
Is the recommended socket count 1 or 2?
Any other recommendations please?

This question is similar to: Can you help me with my capacity planning?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi @vidarlo This is not relating to capacity planning. I already know what capacity I want. It is relating to specific requirements for Exchange + ESXi, as there are special requirements according to the links given. I'm just trying to figure out whether I have understood it correctly, with regards to min and max socket count + hyper-threading.

There's a big gap between "probably the most important VM" and everything else. How much CPU each node actually gets will depend on the demand from ALL of them - your ESX config is less than half the story.

Hyperthreading is ok to be enabled nowadays (where it wasn't before)? Hyperthreading has always been ok for Exchange on virtuals. It was for running Exchange on bare metal physical servers where it had to be disabled.


The ratio of physical cores to virtual CPUs should ideally be 1:1, meaning no oversubscription. This helps to ensure that virtual machine performance does not suffer due to resource contention.

If hyperthreading is enabled, hyperthreaded cores should not be counted as physical cores. Hyperthreading can increase throughput, but they should not be counted against the kernel quota because they do not provide the same computational power as physical kernels.

should not oversubscribe memory or use dynamic memory allocation. This helps ensure that Exchange Server has sufficient memory resources to maintain its performance and stability.


